# What exactly is surreal star? What does it mean that it is incomparable to zero?

Tags: order-theory, philosophy, combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

I have been thinking about this for a while & I am perplexed.

What *exactly* is surreal [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(game_theory))? I am aware that it is a [fuzzy game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_game). What I don't understand is what exactly that *means*. Wikipedia says a fuzzy game is:

> *incomparable* with the [zero game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_game); it is not greater than 0, which would be a win for Left; nor less than 0 which would be a win for Right; nor equal to 0 which would be a win for the second player to move. It is therefore a first-player win.

This brings me to the first thing I don't understand: what does it mean for a value to be incomparable to a number? I have read the answer to [Distinction between “fuzzy” and “confused with.”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982889/distinction-between-fuzzy-and-confused-with), however I still do not really comprehend *why* star & zero are incomparable.

A part of my confusion is that in the [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) there is the concept of $\uparrow$, which is defined as $\{0|*\}$ (greater than zero & less than star) & $\downarrow$, which is defined as $\{*|0\}$ (greater than star & less than zero). If star & zero are *incomparable*, how can this comparison be made?

Comment: Kais Hasan proposed an edit that changed "a" to "the", making the quote from Wikipedia inaccurate. amWhy fixed the grammar post-edit, but it was still not quoting [the Wikipedia page for "Fuzzy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_game) accurately. I edited that part back.

Comment: Incidentally, for a description of $*$ as a game people can play, see [my answer to "What does she mean by star?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/235435/26369).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Numbers and Games

The $\{a,b\mid c,d,e\}$ notation used for surreal numbers is also used for representing certain games more generally. Basically, a "game" lets you put any sets of games as the left and right set. But a game is only a (surreal) number if all elements of those sets are numbers and no right element is less than or equal to any left element. For clarity, $*$ and $\uparrow$ are not (surreal) numbers, just games.

It turns out that numbers have nice properties: If $x=\{a\mid b\}$ is a number, then $a<x<b$ is true. However, that does ***not*** hold for games in general. So "greater than zero & less than star" is not a correct way of thinking of "$\{0\mid*\}$".

---

## Definition of Inequality

To understand the meaning of inequalities and what incomparable would mean, we need a definition of inequality for games. There are a few equivalent definitions, but one that takes the least work to set up is given in Claus Tøndering's [Surreal Numbers -- An Introduction](https://www.tondering.dk/download/sur.pdf). Paraphrased, Definition 2 says:

> $x\le y$ if and only if $y$ is less than or equal to no member of $x$'s left set, and no member of $y$'s right set is less than or equal to $x$.

Now that we have this recursive definition of $x\le y$, we can define other (in)equality symbols:

- $x=y$ when $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ both hold.
- $x<y$ when $x\le y$ holds but $y\le x$ does not.
- $x\not\gtrless y$ ($x$ is "incomparable to" $y$) when neither of $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ hold.

You can see a notation-heavy use of this definition of $\le$ in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3566537/26369) explaining in detail how to check that $\{0\mid1\}$ is a number.

---

## How can things be incomparable?

For example, consider the game (not a number) $s=\{1\mid-1\}$. If you check the definition of inequality above (or any equivalent one), you'll find that it's greater than $-2$ and less than $2$. But $s\le1$ and $1\le s$ are both false, so that $s$ is "incomparable to"/"confused with" $1$ (we might write $s\not\gtrless 1$). Similarly, $s$ is  confused with $0$ (so "fuzzy") and confused with $-1$ as well. It is simply *not* true that "$s$ is somehow greater than $1$ and less than $-1$".

Your examples of $*=\{0\mid0\}$ and $\uparrow=\{0\mid*\}$ are similar. $*<1$ is true but $*\le0$ and $0\le*$ are not true (so $*\not\gtrless 0$). $0<\uparrow$ happens to be true, but $\uparrow\le*$ and $*\le\uparrow$ are not true (so $\uparrow\not\gtrless *$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I understand numbers, but not games. It is confusing to me that $\uparrow\not\gtrless *$ & $0\not\gtrless *$ but not $\uparrow\not\gtrless 0$.

Comment: @user773237 It's definitely weird. Maybe it's a bit less weird with definitions of how to play these "games" as actual games, and conditions for inequalities corresponding to who has a winning strategy in certain games.